# Python packaging: run setup.py automatically

Tags: python, github, packaging, githooks

I'm using setup.py for registering some of my packages which are using by other packages.

I'm storing my project on GitHub and want to run `python setup.py install` after cloning my repository or after running `git pull` by users who have cloned my repo previously.

Is it possible at all?

P.S. I was looking for some git hooks, but didn't find something interesting.

Comment: What did you find when researching git hooks?

Comment: `applypatch` and `update` looks more or less interesting for me, but looking through `*.sample` files, it looks like both of them are for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way of making it work post-clone (without git repo template hackery but then that would likely apply to *all* of your repositories).

As for `pull`, you can use the `post-merge` hook: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge (from experience, this doesn't seem to run for merge conflicts -- but that's probably fine for the general case).

For checkout, there's [post-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout)

An aside: I'd suggest using `pip` instead of `python setup.py ...`, but that's not the point of this question

Comment: What do you mean under `use pip instead of python setup.py`? Publish my package into Pypy and install it via pip?

Comment: `pip install .` is generally a better idea than `python setup.py install` -- also I believe you mean pypi instead of pypy [a python interpreter written in python](https://pypy.org)